# How to have long web loading?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I got problem with my loader. I am a young graphic designer I was doing research to create a loader with codes. I have everything for now but the problem is that I would like my charger to be seen and not be instantaneous
I share with you my code that I used the JS code:

```
jQuery(window).load(function(){
  jQuery('#loading').fadeOut();
});
```

Thanks guys for kindly helping me have a good day !

Answer (score 1):

The `.fadeOut()` function has a speed of `400 milliseconds` by default.
This means the fade animation (visible -> invisible) will take 0.4 seconds.

If you want the animation to take more time, you can simply add your desired duration (in milliseconds) as an integer as first parameter for `.fadeOut()` function.

`.fadeOut(1500)` <-- this will increase the animation duration to 1.5 seconds.

You can find more details in [jQuery documentation](https://api.jquery.com/fadeout/)

Answer (score 1):

Add delay & increase number value

```
$("#loading").delay(7000).fadeOut("slow");
```